# elseif condition not working

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I have several conditions that I'm looking for to output different styling. Everything works but this one section and I can't for the life of me understand why it won't output what I want.

I can verify in the database that there are records that contain the two conditions. In my case, I'm looking at:

```
elseif (($t4 == '' || $t4 == NULL )&& $nordvmfollowup == '1'){      
echo '<tr>
  <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
  <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
  <td ><div align="left">NF</div></td>
  <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
  </tr>';       

          }
```

Just after my while I have:

```
$t4 = $row['postT4'];
$nordvmfollowup = $row['nordvmfollowup'];
```

I have tried doing the following conditions and nothing will output the letters NF in the cell.

```
 elseif ($t4 == '' && $nordvmfollowup == '1')
 elseif ($t4 == NULL && $nordvmfollowup == '1')
 elseif (($t4 == '' || $t4 == NULL ) && $nordvmfollowup == '1')
 elseif ((!isset($t4)) && $nordvmfollowup == '1')
```

All of the other conditional statements work, which leads me to think I can't

My code in full:

```
<?php
    define('DB_SERVER', "xxxx");
    define('DB_USER', "xxxx");
    define('DB_PASSWORD', "xxxx");
    define('DB_TABLE', "xxxx");

    // The procedural way
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
        trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $query = "
        SELECT i131.pdoseID, i131.patientID, i131.lastname, i131.firstname, i131.dose, i131.date_injected, i131.pre_tapazole_t4 AS preT4, i131.recheck_t4 AS postT4, i131.datechecked, b.breed, g.gender, i131.recheck_t4_range_low, i131.recheck_t4_range_high, i131.deceased, i131.nordvmfollowup, i131.recheck_t4

        FROM tbl_I131_data i131

        LEFT JOIN tbl_I131_breeds b
        ON i131.breed = b.breedID

        LEFT JOIN tbl_I131_gender g
        ON i131.gender = g.genderID

        WHERE i131.isotope = '1'
        GROUP BY i131.pdoseID, i131.patientID, i131.lastname, i131.firstname, i131.dose, i131.date_injected, i131.pre_tapazole_t4, i131.recheck_t4, i131.datechecked, b.breed, g.gender, i131.recheck_t4_range_low, i131.recheck_t4_range_high, i131.deceased, i131.nordvmfollowup
        ORDER BY i131.date_injected DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

    echo "
    <table width='1280px;' class='tablesorter-dropbox table-responsive ui-table-reflow'>";
    echo "<thead class='thead-inverse'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='filter-false' data-sorter='false'><div align='left'>&nbsp;</div></th>
        <th ><div align='left'>Patient ID</div></th>
        <th ><div align='left'>Last Name</div></th>
        <th ><div align='left'>First Name</div></th>
        <th class='filter-select filter-onlyAvail'><div align='left'>Breed</div></th>
        <th class='filter-select filter-onlyAvail'><div align='left'>Gender</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false' ><div align='left'>Date Injected</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false' data-sorter='false'><div align='left'>Dose</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false'><div align='left'>Pre Tx T4</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false' ><div align='left'>Post Tx T4</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false'><div align='left'>Recheck Date</div></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tfoot>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='filter-false' data-sorter='false'><div align='left'>&nbsp;</div></th>
        <th ><div align='left'>Patient ID</div></th>
        <th ><div align='left'>Last Name</div></th>
        <th ><div align='left'>First Name</div></th>
        <th class='filter-select filter-onlyAvail'><div align='left'>Breed</div></th>
        <th class='filter-select filter-onlyAvail'><div align='left'>Gender</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false' ><div align='left'>Date Injected</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false' data-sorter='false'><div align='left'>Dose</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false'><div align='left'>Pre Tx T4</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false' ><div align='left'>Post Tx T4</div></th>
        <th class='filter-false'><div align='left'>Recheck Date</div></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th colspan='11' class='ts-pager'>";
    echo "<div class='form-inline'>";
    echo "      <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm mx-1' role='group'>";
    echo "        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary first' title='first'>⇤</button>";
    echo "        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary prev' title='previous'>←</button>";
    echo "      </div>";
    echo "      <span class='pagedisplay'></span>";
    echo "      <div class=btn-group btn-group-sm mx-1' role='group'>";
    echo "        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary next' title='next'>→</button>";
    echo "        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary last' title='last'>⇥</button>";
    echo "      </div>";
    echo "      <select class='form-control-sm custom-select px-1 pagesize' title='Select page size'>";
    echo "        <option selected='selected' value='15'>15</option>";
    echo "        <option value='30'>30</option>";
    echo "        <option value='50'>50</option>";
    echo "        <option value='100'>100</option>";
    echo "        <option value='all'>All Rows</option>";
    echo "      </select>";
    echo "      <select class='form-control-sm custom-select px-4 mx-1 pagenum' title='Select page number'></select>";
    echo "    </div>";
    echo "   </th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tfoot>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    if($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            if ($row['datechecked']==''){
                $datechecked = NULL;
                    }
            else {
                $datechecked = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['datechecked']));
                }   

        $t4 = $row['postT4'];
        $t4_low = $row['recheck_t4_range_low'];
        $t4_high = $row['recheck_t4_range_high'];
        $deceased = $row['deceased'];
        $nordvmfollowup = $row['nordvmfollowup'];




    if ($t4 == '' && $deceased == ''){      
     echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">&nbsp;</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
            </tr>';       

      }     

    elseif ($t4 == '' && $deceased == '1'){     
     echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"><div align="left">&nbsp;</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
            </tr>';       

      }     

    elseif (($t4 == '' || $t4 == NULL )&& $nordvmfollowup == '1'){      
     echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
            <td ><div align="left">NF</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
            </tr>';       

      }     


    elseif ($t4 <= $t4_low) {           
     echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#e4ffc9"><div align="left">'.$row['postT4'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
            </tr>';       

      }

    elseif ($t4 >= $t4_low && $t4 < $t4_high){          
     echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['postT4'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
            </tr>';       

      }     

    elseif ($t4 >= $t4_high){       
     echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ff8494"><div align="left">'.$row['postT4'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
            </tr>';       

      } 

        }




    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";

        }
    else {
      echo 'All wipe tests have been completed';
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    ?>
```

Comment: I smell a `==` vs `===` fight.

Comment: echo values for all variables, which you use in conditions `elseif` and you understand what is wrong

Comment: Please! Read about "separation of concerns"

Comment: if `$deceased` can only be 0 / empty or 1, you will never reach that condition as one of the 2 conditions before that will be met.

Comment: `$t4 == ''` is the same as `$t4 == NULL`. `$t4 === ''` is not the same as `$t4 === NULL`

Comment: $t4 == NULL is not right use is_null($t4) instead

Comment: Any reason `empty($t4)` never worked out? It covers all of those '' null empty 0 conditions.

Comment: as I have stated in the body of my message. ALL of the other conditions work just fine. It is only this one condition (which is not different than the $t4 == '' && $deceased == '1'    

It is only when I add in the $nordvmfollowup that this SINGLE elseif condition does not work. I have tried all of the suggestions provided here and yet it still remains a blank cell.

Comment: is just one column that have value based on condition?

Comment: @DaniëlCronk What are the possible values of `$deceased`?

Comment: @jeroen null or 1   -- it is a TINYINT as it contains the data from a checkbox.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk That's what I thought, I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic problem: Your condition probably works fine, but it is never evaluated because either of the two previous ones has already been met.

Your code looks like:

```
if ($t4 == '' && $deceased == ''){  
    // some code
  }     

elseif ($t4 == '' && $deceased == '1'){ 
    // some code
  }     

elseif (($t4 == '' || $t4 == NULL )&& $nordvmfollowup == '1'){  
    // some code
  }   

...
```

And you have confirmed in the comments that `$deceased` can be empty or 1.

So the third condition will never be reached / match as the first 3 conditions of your code translate to:

```
if ($t4 == ''){ 

  // If this condition is not met... 
  if ($deceased == ''){  
    // some code
  }     

  // Then this condition is met.
  elseif ($deceased == '1'){ 
    // some code
  }     

  // So this condition is never evaluated.
  elseif ($nordvmfollowup == '1'){  
    // some code
  }   

}

...
```

So while `$t4 == ''` (is empty), either one of the 2 inner conditions is `true` so the third condition will never be reached.

Comment: This worked the best. though, it would not work when I did the deceased conditions first. Moving the $nordvmfollowup condition to be the first, it then worked as I had hoped. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing closing 'div' on this line:

```
<td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</td>
```

Try this code, replace from `if($result) {` until EOF:

```
if($result)
{
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
    {
        if ( $row['datechecked'] == '')
        {
            $datechecked = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            $datechecked = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['datechecked']));
        }

        $t4 = $row['postT4'];
        $t4_low = $row['recheck_t4_range_low'];
        $t4_high = $row['recheck_t4_range_high'];
        $deceased = $row['deceased'];
        $nordvmfollowup = $row['nordvmfollowup'];
        echo '<tr>
            <td><div valign="top" align="center">' . '<a class="btn-sm btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="insert_patient_data.php?id=' . $row['pdoseID'] . '"> ' . "Edit". '</a>' . '</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['lastname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['firstname'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['breed'].'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>
            <td><div valign="top" align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date_injected'])).'</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['dose'].' mCi</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">'.$row['preT4'].'</div></td>';

        if ($t4 == '' && $deceased == '')
        {     
            echo '<td><div align="left">&nbsp;</div></td>';

        }elseif ($t4 == '' && $deceased == '1')
        {
            echo '<td bgcolor="#000000"><div align="left">&nbsp;</div></td>';

        }elseif (($t4 == '' || $t4 == NULL ) && $nordvmfollowup == '1')
        {
            echo '<td ><div align="left">NF</div></td>';
        }elseif ($t4 <= $t4_low)
        {          
            echo '<td bgcolor="#e4ffc9"><div align="left">'.$row['postT4'].'</div></td>';

        }elseif ($t4 >= $t4_low && $t4 < $t4_high)
        {
            echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['postT4'].'</div></td>;
                <td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
                </tr>';    
        }elseif ($t4 >= $t4_high){
            echo '<td bgcolor="#ff8494"><div align="left">'.$row['postT4'].'</div></td>';

        }
        echo '<td><div align="left">'.$datechecked.'</div></td>
             </tr>';
    }
}else
{
    echo '<tr><td colspan="11">All wipe tests have been completed</td></tr>';
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

I didn't check about logic condition, because I don't know the data and the goal.